# show and hide tables by Date

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some tables ordered by Date from 2016 to 2003

trying to figure out a way to show and hide these tables by date.

```
       <select id="Years">
            <option value="y2016">2016</option>
            <option value="y2015">2015</option>
            <option value="y2014">2014</option>
        </select>

<div class="TableView">
            <table class="y2016" width="100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th height="23">Date</th>
                        <th height="23">Subject</th>
                        <th height="23">Description</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>06/14/16</td>
                        <td>Cost Management Report as of 6/14/2016</td>
                        <td>June <a href="">Cost Management Report</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>03/10/16</td>
                        <td>Cost Management Report as of 3/10/2016</td>
                        <td>March <a href="" target="_blank">Report </a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>05/21/15</td>
                        <td>April - Cost Management Report</td>
                        <td>April <a href="" target="_blank">Report</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>04/06/15</td>
                        <td>March - Cost Management Report</td>
                        <td>March <a href="" target="_blank">Report</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>02/06/15</td>
                        <td>January - Cost Management Report</td>
                        <td>January <a href="" target="_blank">Report</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

div class="Tables">
            <table class="y2015" width="100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th height="23">Date</th>
                        <th height="23">Subject</th>
                        <th height="23">Description</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>05/21/15</td>
                        <td>April - Cost Management Report</td>
                        <td>April <a href="" target="_blank">Report</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>04/06/15</td>
                        <td>March - Cost Management Report</td>
                        <td>March <a href="" target="_blank">Report</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>02/06/15</td>
                        <td>January - Cost Management Report</td>
                        <td>January <a href="" target="_blank"> Report</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>10/31/14</td>
                        <td>Response to Notice of Violation</td>
                        <td><a href="">report</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>10/31/14</td>
                        <td>October - Cost Management Report</td>
                        <td>October <a href="http://www.dpw.co.santa-cruz.ca.us/Sanitation/CSA7CMR103114.pdf" target="_blank">Cost Management Report</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

so y2016 will display then I will choose y2015 and that will display the 2015 table and so on.

any suggestions I had a script but that only showed and hide only on year.

Comment: Can you provide the HTML and CSS you have for your tables?

Comment: at the moment no css, but I was thinking of doing a display none with CSS or just have jquery handle that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, change your definitions and use ids for your tables. Set the css on each table to display:none.
Then, use an event handler for your select so that on change, the correct table will be shown. 
See the code below. Specifically, note that I changed the classes to id on your tables, and then look at the small javascript function that I wrote at the bottom of the page.
Oh, and that I added an option to the Select so that a user will have to select the year.

```
    </style>

    </head>  
    <body>
<select id="Years">
<option>Select Year</option>
        <option value="y2016">2016</option>
        <option value="y2015">2015</option>
        <option value="y2014">2014</option>
    </select>

<div class="Tables">
        <table id="y2016" width="100%" style = 'display:none;'>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th height="23">Date</th>
                    <th height="23">Subject</th>
                    <th height="23">Description</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>06/14/16</td>
                    <td>Cost Management Report as of 6/14/2016</td>
                    <td>June <a href="">Cost Management Report</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>03/10/16</td>
                    <td>Cost Management Report as of 3/10/2016</td>
                    <td>March <a href="" target="_blank">Report </a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>05/21/15</td>
                    <td>April - Cost Management Report</td>
                    <td>April <a href="" target="_blank">Report</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>04/06/15</td>
                    <td>March - Cost Management Report</td>
                    <td>March <a href="" target="_blank">Report</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>02/06/15</td>
                    <td>January - Cost Management Report</td>
                    <td>January <a href="" target="_blank">Report</a></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>


        <table id="y2015" width="100%" style = 'display:none;'>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th height="23">Date</th>
                    <th height="23">Subject</th>
                    <th height="23">Description</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>05/21/15</td>
                    <td>April - Cost Management Report</td>
                    <td>April <a href="" target="_blank">Report</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>04/06/15</td>
                    <td>March - Cost Management Report</td>
                    <td>March <a href="" target="_blank">Report</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>02/06/15</td>
                    <td>January - Cost Management Report</td>
                    <td>January <a href="" target="_blank"> Report</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>10/31/14</td>
                    <td>Response to Notice of Violation</td>
                    <td><a href="">report</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>10/31/14</td>
                    <td>October - Cost Management Report</td>
                    <td>October <a href="http://www.dpw.co.santa-cruz.ca.us/Sanitation/CSA7CMR103114.pdf" target="_blank">Cost Management Report</a></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
                <script>
    $("#Years").on('change', function(){
    var tbl = $("#Years option:selected").val();
    $("#" + tbl).show();
    })
    </script>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set up a change listener on `#Years` (using jQuery because you tagged it with jQuery):

```
$('#Years').change(function(){
    // Hide all tables
    $('table').hide();
    // Get the current value of #Years
    var val = $(this).val();
    // Show the correct table
    $('.' + val).show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make some minute change in HTML. Instead of adding class to table add it to the parent `div` of the each table

**HTML**

```
<div class="TableView y2016"> // add y2016 class to here
  <table class="" width="100%">
    // Rest of code
  </table>
</div>

<div class="TableView y2015"> // add y2015 class to her
  <table class="" width="100%">
    //Rest of code
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

**CSS**

```
.TableView { // will hide all tables
  display: none
}
.y2016{  // will show only table.y2016 since y2016 is default selected
  display:block;
}
```

**JS**

```
$("#Years").on('change',function(event){
// get value of selected option
var _getSelected =$( "#Years option:selected" ).val(); 
$('.TableView').css('display','none'); // hide all other tables
$('.'+_getSelected).css('display','block'); // only show selected table
})
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/t4tvn9zs/1/)

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result use below option

JS:

```
$('#Years').on('change', function() {
  var year = $(this).val();
  var yearVal = year.substring(3);

  $("tr").each(function() {
    $this = $(this)
    var value = $this.find("td:first").html();
    if (value) {
      var selVal = value.slice(-2);
      if (selVal === yearVal) {
        $(this).show();
      } else {
        $(this).hide();
      }
    }
  });
})
```

http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/yJEYgq